# How safe is the Android password field?

Tags: android, security, password-protection

I could (and still might) do this research myself, but I'm curious about the safety of  password fields in android apps. I became curious of this when I saw an app on the PlayStore "Inputting++" which requires enabling of accessibility permissions.

Does the android system prevent apps from accessing input when the user is focused on an edittext with its inputtype being "password"? I assume yes but am interested in the subject, any extra info on how that works would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

As a html password input, is not encryption.